# Que ferramentas devo usar para criar um aplicativo android

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, kotlin

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento mobile que será feito em Java ou Kotlin e minha dúvida é que ferramentas posso usar tanto na parte do design como no banco de dados quais são as principais tecnologias ?

Comment: Tudo é importante, por exemplo, mesmo que tenha diversos bancos dados possíveis, cada um tem sua vantagem e desvantagem e será usado para coisas diferentes. Mas dependendo do que pretende, sugiro que, antes de focar em apps android nativo, de uma olhada nos PWA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Design**

Olá, uma das melhores dicas para vocês é, inicialmente, projetar as suas telas com o software gratuito Gravit Design, como ele você poderá criar absolutamente todas as telas do seu app, pois lá você encontra ícones para tudo, pode ficar muito real.

**Desenvolvimento**

Sem dúvida, o desenvolvimento será com o Android Studio. Caso ele consuma muita memória do seu PC você poderá utilizar o seu próprio celular Android para emular suas aplicações.

**Banco de Dados**

Há várias ferramentas para trabalhar com banco de dados, mas uma dica muito boa que lhe dou é evitar inicialmente o uso de banco de dados SQL por exemplo para armazenar informações que não sejam mídias (imagens, video, musicas e etc). Caso o seu app armazene somente valores primitivos como inteiros, floats, Strings etc, você poderá usar SharePreferences que é extremamente fácil.

**Armazenamento online**

O melhor armazenamento online até então é o firebase, com ele as suas possibilidades são incríveis e muito completa, vale conferir.

**Exemplo de app**

Criei um app utilizando absolutamente todas as ferramentas descritas acima, confira: [App Intercampi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edesonabizerril.newintercampi)

Answer (score 2):

Ferramentas e tecnologias que uso no atual momento:

**IDE**

Android Studio

**Design**

O próprio Android Studio mexendo no xml e na aba de design, olhando a preview. Também estou tentando usar Constraint layout e as guidelines do material design.

**Banco de Dados Local**

Realm e/ou SharedPreferences (Hawk - https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk)

**Repositórios de Código**

Github ou Bitbucket